# How to remove broken PPAs using Terminal at once?

Tags: apt, lubuntu, ppa, 19.04

I have lots of broken PPAs that I like to get rid of, but since I have lots of PPAs in general, deleting them by hand is not an option. I want to somehow delete all broken PPAs at once. Thank you for your help!

EDIT: [This is the result of `sudo apt-get update | grep Failed`](https://pastebin.com/MiiLHZYX). I think this might be a good indicator whether a PPA is broken or not.

Comment: I don't know any general method, that can tell the difference between good and broken PPAs. But you can try `sudo add-apt-repository -r ppa:whatever-you-want-to-remove` for each PPA that you want to get rid of.

Comment: @sudodus PPAs that fail when calling `apt-get update` shall be a good indicator IMO.

Comment: In that case you can use that information in a shellscript file in order to decide which PPAs to treat with `add-apt-repository -r`

Comment: @sudodus I'm not very good with shellscripts. Could you write me one? here's the output of `sudo apt-get update | grep Failed`.  https://pastebin.com/MiiLHZYX

Comment: I don't say no, but I can't do it now. Let us hope that someone else has better time this weekend and can help you.

Comment: General questions first... how do you know you have broken PPA's? How many good/bad PPA's do you have? How hard is it to fix the broken PPA's, and do you care to? If you start `Software & Updates`, `Other Software` tab, you should be able to control-select bad PPA's and then click the `Remove` button.

Comment: @heynnema I have edited my post for more info.

Comment: Please see my answer. Please remember to accept it if it was helpful. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

We really don't discuss 19.04 until later this month when it's formally released. You caused these problems mostly by prematurely upgrading to a as yet unreleased version of Ubuntu.

However, to solve your problem...

```
is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:50 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/vivaldi.list:3
```

It tells you right there where the problem is. You have the same repository entered twice, once in sources.list line 50, and vivaldi.list line 3. View vivadi.list, and then edit sources.list and remove the duplicate entry on line 50.

```
The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/brightbox/ruby-ng/ubuntu disco Release' does not have a Release file.
```

Because you upgraded to 19.04 prematurely, some PPA's got updated to the `disco` release prematurely, and those don't exist yet. Edit each of these and use `cosmic`, or some older Ubuntu release. Easiest to do this in `Software & Updates` application.